# Waiting for threading.Event until Frame closes

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I've written a GUI and at some point a frame is opened as child of the mainframe and the function which opened the other frame should only continue when this frame is closed.

I just don't understand why this isn't working:

```
def ShowFrame(completeEvent):
    frame = MyFrame(self, completeEvent, ...)
    frame.Show()

self.completeEvent = threading.Event()
thread = threading.Thread(target=ShowFrame, args=(self.completeEvent,))
thread.start()
self.completeEvent.wait()
```

Running this example results in a frozen mainframe and "MyFrame" never appears.
It seems like thread isn't started and even waits for the completeEvent or it is started but didn't reach the start-command... what I just don't understand.
Normally MyFrame should appear and when I close it the completeEvent is set and the mainFrame continues. I've also tried wx.CallAfter, but that doesn't help either...
Could somebody tell me how to make the mainframe wait until the other frame is closed without making it a dialog or with makemodal or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform GUI functions on another thread.

I would just do this:

```
class ParentFrame(wx.Frame):
    ...
    def show_child(self):
        frame = ChildFrame(self)
        frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_child_closed)
        frame.Show()
    def on_child_closed(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        # do processing needed after child closes

class ChildFrame(wx.Frame):
    ...
```

Comment: That would be possible, of course. But there must be a possibility to stop a function at some point and to continue it after something else happened. What is a threading.Event for if this does not work? I "only" have to work two frames - in this case - parallel... I thought thread.Thread is exactly what I need

Comment: `ShowModal` with a `wx.Dialog` is the general way to accomplish that if you don't want the user to interact with the parent frame while using the child dialog. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: A dialog is no option, because the frame is very complex and derives from other frame-classes. What I'm trying to do is something like: start a function in a frame, during this the function checks if too many elements are in a container-class-object. If so, pause the funtion and start another frame to choose some of those elements and resume the function with the chosen elements instead of all... Something like a Multi- or SingleChoiceDialog, but with a frame.